# Tomcat (v7.0.47) behind Apache2 HTTPD (v2.4.23): connection fails after Java upgrade

Tags: apache, tomcat7

We are running a legacy application on an Apache v7.0.47 server behind an Apache2 HTTPD proxy (v2.4.23).
I am trying to upgrade the Java version on the server (used by both the proxy as well as the tomcat) from v1.8.0_181 to v1.8.0_303.

After that upgrade the Tomcat does not respond any more to the Apache's passed-on requests (the application itself comes up and runs fine).

Both the Apache on its network facing side as well as Apache and Tomcat among each other were configured to "talk" TLS1.2 already for a while, so I don't think that the disabling of TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 in the later Java version is the cause of the issue here. And there is no error message in the logs giving any clue. The only indication is, that the Tomcat seems to close and tear down the connection without any response after having receiving the request. That seems to happen already in the SSL layer, since there is no entry in the access-log (of Tomcat).

Switching back to the "old" Java gets things going again, so firewall, network etc. are definitely NOT the issue here. With the newer Java version the connection setup fais again, causing the HTTPD to emit a "502 Bad gateway" error.

Any idea anyone what could cause the Tomcat to reject the HTTPD's requests just based on the Java version? Additional SSL verifications enabled by default in the newer stack? I searched extensively but didn't surface any suspect, yet.

Later addition: trying to identify the issue I found out that with Java v1.8.0_231 things are still working, with v1.8.0_241 and higher it fails.
Inspecting the release notes now to find a hint...

Any ideas or experiences with that upgrade anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records - in case someone else stumbles over this question:

The issue here was that from Java v1.8.0_241 on upwards Java security verifies that a certificate chain read from a certificate store is rooted in a CA certificate that has a proper CA-flag. Since we were using an old certificate and trust store that had been generated with an old release of the java keytool back than this flag was missing and the new Java version thus rejected *all* the entries in that certificate file. It thus aborted the SSL connection setup and simply closed the connection without any response or indication.

There is a VM option `-Djdk.security.allowNonCaAnchor=true` that one can add to Tomcat's JAVA_OPTS variable (typically in a file `setenv.sh`) to disable this verification. After adding that our Tomcat was again responding to SSL-requests and worked OK again.

BTW: when trying to analyze SSL issues like the above the option `-Djavax.net.debug=all:handshake:verbose` proved to be a real live-saver! With this option one gets very details log output and can follow SSL handshakes and connection setups in detail. Once I had finally gotten a first useful error message pointing to this CA-flag issue searching for a solution (or rather workaround in this case) proved to be a snap compared to the initial search for what could be the issue here.